Significance & Relevance of the Metric Differential for Maps into Metric Spaces.
I came across a generalization of the derivative for a map $ f: \mathbb{R}^n \to X $, where $ (X, d) $ is a metric space.
The Metric Differential of $ f $ in the direction of $ v \in \mathbb{R}^n $ at $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n $ is defined as:

$\large
(\|\nabla\|_v f)(x) := \large\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \Large\frac{d(f(x+tv), f(x))}{t},
$
whenever the limit exists.

This definition intrigued me, but I am unsure about its significance. For example, in the special case where $ X = \mathbb{R}^m $, this limit reduces to:

$\large
\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \Large\frac{\|f(x+tv) - f(x)\|_{\mathbb{R}^m}}{t}
$

which resembles but is not exactly the usual partial derivative of $ f $ in the direction of $ v $. In fact, this limit exists if and only if $f$ is flat at $x$ along the direction of $v$ i.e. iff the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ along $v$ viz. $\large(\nabla_vf)(x)=0$.
The above observations prompt me to raise a few questions:
$(a)$ Does this definition have any meaningful interpretation in modern mathematics, particularly in the context of topology, geometry, or analysis?
$(b)$ Are there scenarios where this concept could indeed provide insights that traditional derivatives cannot.
$(c)$ Is this concept used or studied in existing research, or is it merely another formal definition which is just coined for no reasons, lacking significant utility?
I am curious to know if this definition has potential as a research topic or if it plays a role in any well-known problems or theories. Any insights or references from the MSE community members would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

I suspect that the definition should have the limit as $r\to 0^+$. Do you have a source in print in a reliable text or research article?

@TedShifrin Sir, I found it in the Wikipedia. There they have no restriction on the direction of $r\to 0$. Here is the link to the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_differential

@TedShifrin I would like to know if we can get something richer if we modify the definition of the metric differential by replacing the denominator with $|t|$ as $t$ approaches to $0$.

Wikipedia is full of errors. I suspect this is one. I think my suggestion may give a more interesting setting than yours — yours requires a symmetry as you move in directions in $v$ and $-v$. Wikipedia gives a reference; I would suggest that you track it down. I retired ten years ago and no longer have access to journals or a library.

@TedShifrin Thank you Sir. I will surely track it down.
